# Running Firefox Add-on on Android using jpm-mobile

Tags: android, node.js, firefox

I am trying to run simple Firefox Add-on (works well on PC) on Android tablet.
I have performed all actions described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Mobile_development) to set up environment
and trying to run

```
jpm-mobile run --adb "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe"
```

The output is

```
Running Firefox instance ...
Starting Firefox with /mnt/sdcard/jetpack-profile
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
Starting: Intent { act=android.activity.MAIN cmp=/mnt/sdcard/jetpack-profile (has extras) }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {/mnt/sdcard/jetpack-profile} does not exist.
```

As I understand the **cmp=** should be **org.mozilla.fennec/.App**
Trying to fix this I found this code in *...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jpm-mobile\lib*

```
function amStart(options) {

console.log("Starting Firefox with " + options.profile);

var p = cp.spawn(options.adb, [
          "shell",
          "am start",
          "-a",
          "android.activity.MAIN",
          "-n",
          options.intent + "/.App",
          "--es",
          "args",
          "-profile " + options.profile
      ], makeOptions(options));
```

When this lines are removed

```
      "--es",
      "args",
      "-profile " + options.profile
```

Firefox Nightly is started but my add-on is not installed.

I also tried to run this

```
am start -a android.activity.MAIN -n org.mozilla.fennec/.App --es args -profile /mnt/sdcard/jetpack-profile
```

from adb shell. As the result Firefox is started but add-on is not installed.

The tablet's Android version is 4.2.1

What should I do to get my add-on installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This string

```
"-profile " + options.profile
```

in *C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jpm-mobile\lib\adb.js*
on line 74 should be changed to this

```
"'-profile " + options.profile + "'"
```

From **am** command manual:

```
<INTENT> specifications include these flags and arguments:
    ...
    [-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...]
```

As I understand **-profile /mnt/sdcard/jetpack-profile** is not recognized as `<EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>` because of space character.

Comment: This seems to indeed fix the problem. Has this fix been reported to Mozilla?

Comment: I am not reported this bug. Anyone can use my question and answer to report it.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same Error.

```
Starting Firefox with /mnt/sdcard/jetpack-profile
--------- beginning of main
Starting: Intent { act=android.activity.MAIN cmp=org.mozilla.fennec/.App(has extras) }
--------- beginning of system
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.mozilla.fennec/org.mozilla.fennec.App} does not exist
```

Now i Changed this thing a little bit. I first found out the real name of the firefox app over "adb shell pm list packages". This results in "org.mozilla.firefox_beta/.App".

I hardcoded this one into the adb.js. Now the Error is gone.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify: it's about hardcoding options.intent = 'whatever'; (in my case org.mozilla.firefox) After I set it up, it works with or without applying the chosen solution above.